# Canonical link type with no protocol or domain path, auto-generated with forward slash & file extension

Tags: html, canonical-link

1&1 MyWebsite is automatically generating

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/">
```

for the home page.

I do not have access to the .htaccess file.

Is there a way to remove this auto-generated tag that I'm missing? I want to set the `canonical` link type to the HTTPS protocol with full domain & file extension where necessary. Is this an issue that arises with the SSL certificate? Each page is auto-generating with the forward slash & proceeding file location & extension.

Auto-generated home page tag = `href="/"`.

Comment: Are you sure it’s the webserver and not some application (e.g., a CMS) that runs on this server?

Comment: I've dug through the CMS & you can add Tags in individual page headers & also global header. The auto-generated link seems broke because its not an actual path to anything. There's no apparent setting for the automated canonical link being introduced. I would think that normally the CMS would not set a canonical link, esp. not what it is setting. SEOQuake reports  
>A canonical tag is set for this page, but it can't be reached.

Comment: Which CMS (and relevant plugins/themes) do you use?

Comment: This is in 1&1MyWebsite. I'm not using any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead change the canonical link in dom using Jquery.
See this:
[Replace existing canonical tag with javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067810/replace-existing-canonical-tag-with-javascript-or-jquery)

You can use this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('link[rel="canonical"]').attr('href', 'http://www.yoursite.com');
});
</script>
```